# Swift - Update or insert a row in a section in a tableview without reloading all the data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

**How can I update or insert a row in a tableview without reloading all the data?**

In the ClientsViewController a list of clients is shown alphabetically and separated by sections (first letter of the client`s name).

When I update a client, the tableview shows 2 entries (old and new one) of the same client. When I try to add a client, it crashes.

I think the problem is with indexing.

```
class ClientsViewController:  UITableViewController {

var sortedFirstLetters: [String] = []
var sections: [[Client]] = [[]]
var tableArray = [Client]()
var client: Client?
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

@IBOutlet var noClientsView: UIView!

@IBAction func unwindToClients(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ClientViewController,  let client = sourceViewController.client {

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing client.
            tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
        else {
            // Add a client.
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableArray.count, section: 0)
            tableArray.append(client)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }


        let firstLetters = self.tableArray.map { $0.nameFirstLetter }
        let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

        self.sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
        self.sections = self.sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
            return self.tableArray
                .filter { $0.nameFirstLetter == firstLetter }
                .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
        }

//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                self.tableView.reloadData()
//            }


    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondScene = segue.destination as! ClientViewController
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail", let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let currentPhoto = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        secondScene.client = currentPhoto
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("add")
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
    }
}

@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    getClients()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

}

extension ClientsViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClientsViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.backgroundView = noClientsView
    getClients() //for only the 1st time ==> when view is created ==> ok ish
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    getClients() // not a good idea to make a request to the server everytime the view appears on the screen.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if(self.tableArray.count > 0) {
        return sortedFirstLetters[section]
    }
    else {
        return ""
    }
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    print(sortedFirstLetters)
     return sortedFirstLetters
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let name = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClientCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = name.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = name.city + " - " + name.province
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(sections[section].count > 0) {
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    }
    return sections[section].count
}

func getClients() {

    makeRequest(endpoint: "api/clients/all",
                parameters: [:],
                completionHandler: { (container : ApiContainer<Client>?, error : Error?) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error calling POST on /getClients")
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    self.tableArray = (container?.result)!

                    self.prepareData()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
    } )
}

//sorts and makes the index
func prepareData() {
    let firstLetters = self.tableArray.map { $0.nameFirstLetter }
    let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

    self.sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
    self.sections = self.sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
        return self.tableArray
            .filter { $0.nameFirstLetter == firstLetter }
            .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    }
}

}
```

Bellow is ClientViewController and Client struct.

```
class ClientViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var addressTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var provinceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var postalCodeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contactsLabel: UILabel!

let numberOfRowsAtSection: [Int] = [4, 2]
var client: Client?
var selectedProvince: String?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.title = "New"
    if (client?.client_id) != nil {
        self.title = "Edit"
        nameTextField.text = client?.name
        provinceTextField.text = client?.province
        cityTextField.text = client?.city
        addressTextField.text = client?.address
        postalCodeTextField.text = client?.postal_code
        selectedProvince = client?.province
    }
}


@objc func save(sender: UIButton!) {
    let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    let address = addressTextField.text ?? ""
    let city = cityTextField.text ?? ""
    let province = selectedProvince ?? ""
    let postal_code = postalCodeTextField.text ?? ""
    var endPoint: String

    if (client?.client_id) != nil {
        endPoint = "api/clients/update"
    } else {
        endPoint = "api/clients/add"
    }

    client = Client(name:name, client_id: client?.client_id, postal_code: postal_code, province: province, city: city, address: address)
    let requestBody = makeJSONData(client)

    makeRequestPost(endpoint: endPoint,
                    requestType: "POST",
                    requestBody: requestBody,
                    view: view,
                    completionHandler: { (response : ApiContainer<Client>?, error : Error?) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("error calling POST on /todos")
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }
                        let b = (response?.meta)!
                        let a = (response?.result[0])
                        let client_id = a?.client_id
                        self.client?.client_id = client_id

                        if(b.sucess == "yes") {

                            //change message and use the custom func like on error.
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "All good", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                                (_)in
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToClients", sender: self)
                            })

                            alert.addAction(OKAction)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)                                    
                            })


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Error Creating Client")
                            //return
                        }
    } )
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50.0;

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(save))


    let thePicker = UIPickerView()
    provinceTextField.inputView = thePicker
    thePicker.delegate = self

    // ToolBar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adding Button ToolBar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ClientDetailViewController.doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ClientDetailViewController.cancelClick))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    provinceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

@objc func doneClick() {
    provinceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
@objc func cancelClick() {
    provinceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rows: Int = 0
    if section < numberOfRowsAtSection.count {
        rows = numberOfRowsAtSection[section]
    }
    return rows
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Client"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

    if  segue.identifier == "unwindToClients",
        let destination = segue.destination as? ClientsViewController
    {
        destination.client = client
    }

    if  segue.identifier == "showContacts",
        let destination = segue.destination as? ContactsViewController
    {
        destination.client = client
    }

}


// MARK: - Picker view
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return provinces.count
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return provinces[row].name
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    provinceTextField.text = provinces[row].name
}




}




struct Client: Codable {
var client_id: Int!
let name: String!
let postal_code: String!
let province: String!
let city: String!
let address: String!

init(name: String, client_id: Int! = nil, postal_code: String, province: String, city: String, address: String) {
    self.client_id = client_id
    self.name = name
    self.postal_code = postal_code
    self.province = province
    self.city = city
    self.address = address

}

var nameFirstLetter: String {
    return String(self.name[self.name.startIndex]).uppercased()
}

}
```

Comment: try reloading that particular section only

Answer (score 0):

1. Append the items in datasource at index where you want to insert row in table. than follow steps 2,3,4.
2. Call method tbl.beginupdate
3. call insertRowsAtIndexPaths method of table view
4. Call tbl.endupdate

Comment: still chashes....            tableView.beginUpdates()
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                // Update an existing client.
                tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
            else {
                // Add a client.
...
            }
            tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Checkout any tutorial for insert rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can update tableView rows using this..

```
 self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .top)
```